# Creating a venn diagram with several criterias

Tags: python, venn-diagram

Thank you for reading my question. 
I am a **totally beginner** for python and English is not my primary language. Please ask if you don't understand my English. Thank you for your help.

Here's the question. I want to create a Venn diagram using these criteria:

1. 10*P(B) = P(A)
2. P(C and notA) = 13 * P(B and notC and notA)
3. P(B and C and notA) = 5 * P(B and C and A)
4. P(B and C) = 0.18
5. P(B or C and notA) = 0.07
6. P(notC) = 0.922 -> P(C) = 0.078
7. P(B and A) = 0.01

I tried using 'random' but I think it's quite dumb to do so.
This is my code, but if you have a better solution, please do tell me.

- oa means Only A, i.e. (A and notB and notC)
- abnc: means A and B No C

```
import random
# a = lowgrade fever
# b = headace
# c = Muscle ache
def haha():
    oa = random.random()
    ob = random.random()
    oc = random.random()

    abnc = random.random()
    acnb = random.random()
    bcna = random.random()

    abc = random.random()

    a = oa + abnc + acnb + abc
    b = ob + abnc + bcna + abc
    c = oc + acnb + bcna + abc

    ab = abnc + abc
    ac = acnb + abc
    bc = bcna + abc

    # oa + ob + oc + abnc + acnb+ bcna + abc = 1

    if (10 * b == a):
        c1 = True
    if ((oc + bcna) == 13 * ob):
        c2 = True
    if ((ob + bcna + oc) == 5*abc):
        c3 = True
    if ((bcna + abc) == 0.018):
        c4 = True
    if(ob + bcna + oc == 0.07):
        c5 = True
    if(1 - oc + bcna + abc + acnb == 0.922):
        c6 = True
    if(abnc + abc == 0.01):
        c7 = True

    if (c1 and c2 and c3 and c4 and c5 and c6 and c7):
        allc = True

    if allc:
        print(oa)
        print(ob)
        print(oc)
        print(bcna)
        print(acnb)
        print(abnc)
        print(abc)

    return allc

haha()
while (allc == False):
    haha()
```

Thank you guys.

Comment: What do you mean with a Venn-diagram? What should the expected output look  like? Do you want an image like [this](https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/04/24/23/53/venn-diagram-41217_960_720.png)?

Comment: I just want to know the numbers of each segment(oa, ob, oc, abnc, acnb, bcna and abc). An output of a venn diagram is not necessary.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to find 8 different probabilities. Where ~A means not A. These probabilities are the unknowns of our problem.

```
P( A &  B &  C) [1]
P( A &  B & ~C) [2]
P( A & ~B &  C) [3]
P( A & ~B & ~C) [4]
P(~A &  B &  C) [5]
P(~A & ~B &  C) [6]
P(~A & ~B & ~C) [7]
P(~A &  B & ~C) [8]
```

The first step is to write your equations in the variables written above. We will use `[1]` as a shorthand for `P(A & B & C)`

```
<=> 10P(B) - P(A)=0
<=> 10*([1] + [2] + [5] + [8]) - 1*(([1] + [2] + [3] + [4]) = 0
<=> 9*[1] + 9*[2] + -1*[3]-1*[4] + 10*[5] + 0*[6] + 0*[7] + 10*[8] = 0
```

We can do this for all 7 equations. In linear algebra this is written as a system `Ax = b`. You might remember that you need 8 equations if you have 8 unknown variables. To get a full solution you must find an extra equation. (Hint: what is the sum of all probabilities?)

To solve the exercise in python can use the following code.

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.array([
   [9, 9, -1, -1, 10, 0, 0, 10],  # 10P(B) = P(A)
   ...                            # Insert 7 more equations here
])

b = np.array([0, ....])           # Insert 7 more numbers here

x = np.linalg.solve(A,b)

print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

For convenience, I will use the following shorthand notation:

- `[1--]` denotes P(A),
- `[0--]` denotes P(not A),
- `[0-1]` denotes P(not A and C),
- `[110]` denotes P(A and B and not C),

etc. Using this notation your problem statement can be rewritten as follows:

```
1) 10*[-1-] = [1--]
2) [0-1] = 13*[010]
3) [011] = 5*[111]
4) [-11] = 0.18
5) [-1-] + [001] = 0.07
6) [--1] = 0.078
7) [11-] = 0.01
```

Let us now try to solve it manually:

```
Rewrite 4)
  [011] + [111] = 0.18

Substitute 3 into 4)
  5*[111] + [111] = 0.18
  [111] = 0.03

Rewrite 7) and substitute [111]=0.03
  [110] + [111] = 0.01
  [110] = -0.02
```

A probability cannot be negative, hence we may stop here and conclude that there is no probabilistic solution to your problem.

The obtained result can also be explained as follows:

- P(ABC) ≤ P(AB) = 0.01
- P(~ABC) = 5*P(ABC) ≤ 0.05
- Therefore, P(BC) = P(ABC) + P(~ABC) ≤ 0.01 + 0.05 = 0.06
- This contradicts condition 4.